# Logfile file prcessing in Pig.?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, apache-pig

I have below file format, I am processing in apache pig, this file is unstructured file formate.Could you some idea.

I need pig script....

Current file formate:

```
"GET","https://01.0.01.03:8443/open/config/ui/configuration","{}","{""Accept"":[""application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01""],""Accept-Encoding"":[""gzip, deflate""],""Accept-Language"":[""en-US;q=1""],""Cache-Control"":[""no-cache""],""Connection"":[""keep-alive""],""Content-Type"":[""application""],""Host"":[""01.0.01.01:8443""],""Referer"":["""],""User-Agent"":[""Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0)""],""X-Open-NoSession"":[""true""],""X-Open-Username"":[""anonymous""],""X-Requested-With"":[""XMLHttpRequest""]}","{}",,"SUCCESSFUL",,,"235","MILLISECONDS","[""open-reg""]"
```

OUTPUT FORMATE:

```
GET,https://01.0.01.03:8443/open/config/ui/configuration,,application/json, gzip,en-US,no-cache,keep-alive,application,01.0.01.01,8443,,Mozilla/5.0,true,anonymous,XMLHttpRequest,NULL,NULL,SUCCESSFUL,NULL,NULL,235,MILLISECONDS,open-reg
```

Please help me, for this case study.....

Comment: Is all the column row has same number fields ??

Comment: You can use regex for this.

Comment: Above file is unstructured data format. So i Need unique format. you see the file. "{""Accept"":[""application/json, text/javascript, /; q=0.01""],""Accept-Encoding"":[""gzip, deflate""],""Accept-Language"":[""en-US;q=1""],""Cache-Control"":[""no-cache""],""Connection"":[""keep-alive""],""Content-Type"":[""application""],""Host"":[""01.0.01.01:8443""],""Referer"":["""],""User-Agent"":[""Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0)""],""X-Open-NoSession"":[""true""],""X-Open-Username"":[""anonymous""],""X-Requested-With"":[""XMLHttpRequest""]} ,{}",,"SUCCESSFUL",

Comment: i need all fields for the input file with in unique.